# Set a listener on a specific column with Java, Spring and spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, listener

I am trying to figure out how to set a trigger on a specific column with an entityListener.
I want to trigger a callback funciton every time my ticketName is being modified.

I have an entity, let's say- a Ticket entity:

```
    @Entity
    @EntityListeners (TicketListeners.class)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
        public class Ticket {
    
           private String ticketId
    
           private String ticketName
    
        }
```

Now, as you can see, I set the "EntityListeners" annotation.

My TicketListeners class is:

```
public class TicketListeners {
  @PostUpdate
  public void beforeUpdate(Ticket tickets) {  System.out.println("I am a callback function")}
}
```

With the above code snippets, the callback function is triggered **after** the Ticket object is updated inside the DB, and this is great, but I want my callback funciton to be triggered only if my **ticketName column has changed**.

Any help?

Comment: Checkout Hibernate Listeners https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-interceptors

Comment: Be sure i have alredy did.

Comment: I can't provide a full solution because I don't have so much time. But you have to write an interceptor and check if the ticketName has changed and then do what you want